# Equivalents for the action conditions types in Zabbix 4.0

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I need to filter some of the conditions for the action. In the version 3.0 I tuned it using filtering of the condition types:

```
"filter": {
            "evaltype": "0",
            "conditions": [
                 { "conditiontype": "16", "operator": "7", "value": "", "formulaid": "A" }, { "conditiontype": "5", "operator": "0", "value": "1", "formulaid": "B" }
             ]
         }
```

However in Zabbix 4.0 there is no such types as *trigger value*(16) and *maintenance*(5), so how I can replace them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition type `5` was `trigger value`, and `16` was `maintenance` - looks like you swapped them in the description.

Condition type `5` was dropped [in Zabbix 3.2](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/changes_3.0_-_3.2#action), along with support for trigger value filtering on "OK" values in the frontend - all actions now kick off on PROBLEM events only (although there are recovery operations now). As you were filtering for trigger value of 1 [which is PROBLEM](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/trigger/object#trigger), this means that you can simply drop that condition with Zabbix 4.0.

Condition type `16` has been renamed to `problem is suppressed` [in Zabbix 4.0](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/api/reference/action/object#action_filter_condition), but it should work in a somewhat similar manner as before.